# iPassword backup through unsecured network

Tags: icloud, security, encryption, privacy

I am using the iPassword app on iPhone to store some less and medium important passwords to websites and emails.

I have made probably a silly mistake. I was in the hotel and was using an unsecured public network. I forgot about it and backed up all password content via iCloud and I am worried that this could be visible to someone!

**I have a question:** When the network is still unsecured, is there a chance that a transfer between a device and iCloud would still be encrypted?

Comment: Ah, okay, I'll fix the question title then! My mistake, I just assumed from the capitalisation you meant 1Password. I've also deleted my answer. As for the general question, encryption is certainly possible from 3rd party apps both on the device and while in transit to/from iCloud. However, in terms of iPassword, you're going to have to ask the developer in the comments at the bottom of this [page](https://ilrrong.wordpress.com/ipassword/).

Comment: I understand. My title wasn’t clear. I sent the company this question. do you know by any chance if communication between devices and iCloud is still encrypted regardless of app using their own encryption?

Comment: Great question! But I think it would do better over at [InfoSec](https://security.stackexchange.com). I have asked a moderator.

Comment: Do you have a 1Password subscription?  My understanding is that passwords are encrypted locally before they're uploaded. Plus, Apple encrypts your iCloud backup so you 'might' not have to worry with the double encryption.

Comment: @fsb i don’t have 1Password subscription. The app i have is iPassowrd.

Comment: @Josh Thanks Josh. My first thought was to post it on Information Security but I was afraid it was related to Apple, iPhone, iPad and applications.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, its secure.

---

**Note**: The following is  **way** more info then anyone needs but I thought why not.

---

A while back, around when the internet was created, HTTP, or the **H**yper**t**ext **T**ransfer **P**rotocol, was created to transfer website data. -- *Wait I've seen that before -- Yes you have. In a URL the first section specifies the protocol so when connecting to **http**://example.com you are using the HTTP protocol. When connecting to **ftp**://example.com you are using, yes you guessed it, the FTP protocol, or File Transfer Protocol.* HTTP is an insecure protocol that send data over plain text. Meaning anyone connected to ([or not connected to](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_mode)) the WiFi network can snoop on all passwords, credit cards, addresses, etc. sent over the internet.

**More Info:** https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol

---

iCloud, Google, StackExchange, Yahoo, Chase Bank, Twitter, Spotify, and basically every website ([hopefully](https://letsencrypt.org/about/)) that requires you to login or submit information uses an addition to the HTTP protocol called HTTP**S**, or HTTP + SSL, or secure sockets layer (Yes, us computer people like to shorten things). (In fact, you're using it right now. Look at the URL in on your browser. See the HTTPS?)  SSL Encryption is **EXTREMELY** secure (*[How Secure?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/53596/how-safe-is-ssl?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa), you ask*).  This prevents any data from being snooped on by other people. It encrypts all data sent between the client (you) and the server (the server the website is hosted on).

---

So, since iCloud uses HTTP**S** all the information is secure even if you are on an insecure network.

---